# Javascript each loop issues

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, submit, each

I am having a strange issue & I would like to get some professional feedback.

I am creating a CRM application, where I have a form with preview button. When the preview button is pressed, my function FIRST saves all the fields of the form to a DB via Ajax & then submits the form for preview.

The Form fields are stored in an array (since these fields change). I am looping the array using jQuery.each(myArray, function(index, value).

The problem is the form submits before the loop executes. If I put an alert in the loop or if I add set time out in the document.submit() all works well.

I would like to know, why the loop is not getting completed before going to the next line in the code.

Here is my code.

```
var myArray = ['sub','msg','pic','field4','field5','field6','field7'];
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
       SaveFields(value); // my function that saves to db via Ajax call
     });
  });

//document.formName.submit(); // this submits the form before .each loop can execute
eval("setTimeout('document."+formName+".submit()', 700)"); // THIS WORKS AS INTENDED
```

I also tried to count the array items and added the submit() inside the loop like this...

```
var ArrCount = myArray.length - 1;

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
      var saveIt = SaveFields(value);

        if (ArrCount == index){
        document.formName.submit(); // this also submits the form before .each loop can execute
         }

    });
  });
```

Same results! It will only work with alert or setTimout!

Any help is appreciated because I really want to know why the loop is not getting completed before moving to the next line.

Comment: What does SaveFields do? It seems likely that you're submitting the form before your AJAX request returns.

Comment: SaveFields is a simple jQuerry based ajax function that stores one field at a time.

Comment: I thought about this! submitting the form before AJAX request returns, so I took the SaveFields ajax code and put it inside the .each loop hoping the loop will go through the codes for each item!.... BUT DID NOT MAKE ANY DIFFERENCE GOT THE SAME RESULTS!!!

Comment: THANK YOU! adding async: false to the ajax call fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery.ready function is making your loop execute once the DOM is loaded and ready. Since your document.formName.submit() is outside the ready call, it gets executed immediately. Try moving it inside the ready call, like so:

```
var myArray = ['sub','msg','pic','field4','field5','field6','field7'];
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
    SaveFields(value); 
  });
  document.formName.submit(); 
});
```

Comment: As per the other replies, this will make the form Submit immediately after the page loads. If you want this to happen only when you click the button, then you should replace the jQuery(document).ready with the form's submit handler.

Comment: I tried this, the form will not submit, so added eval(), then the form submits before the loop completing. Added setTimout and it worked as intended. So same behavior inside or out!

Comment: FYI, the above code is inside a function, activated when the button is clicked.

Comment: If SaveFields performs AJAX calls, those are asynchronous, which means code execution continues regardless of whether they have returned or not. You would have to either a) make the calls synchronous so that the form.submit doesn't get called until they are complete, or b) attach the form.submit to the onComplete event of the AJAX call and somehow keep track of how many of them are finished, and only then execute the submit once all of your elements have finished saving

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! Can you tell me how to make the calls synchronous? or how to use the onComplete in this scenario?

Comment: "asynchronous, which means code execution continues regardless of whether they have returned or not"... if the code continues in the background... then the fields must get saved right? BUT it does not. It is as if the loop never executed ANY calls to the function that saves the data!

Comment: If you do 'console.log("saving:',index)' inside the loop, before the SaveFields call and comment out the formName.submit, do you get the messages in the console? Check out the 'async' and 'complete' settings for jQuery.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: Ruy Diaz, THANK YOU! adding async: false to the ajax call fixed the problem! console.log('saving:',index); showed the Array Looping

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is, you're executing the function on page load (or after the timer or alert), seems like you need to do it on submit event.
Something like this should work:

```
$("#formElementId").submit(function() {
  $.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
       SaveFields(value); // my function that saves to db via Ajax call
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Then there's possibly an error on your function. Are you using chrome or firefox+firebug? Can you tell what alert appears on javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .ready() function is an event handler that will only fire when the DOM is loaded. Because the submit() function is called outside the ready() block, execution passes to it once the handler is loaded, not when it fires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your save data method the handler for your form's onSubmit:

```
<form id="myForm" ... onsubmit="return saveAndLoadPreview(this, window.event)">
```

...

```
function saveAndLoadPreview(sender, evt){
    // ajax-post the data
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to set an event handler for the form submit function

for example,

```
$(document).ready(function($){

$("#yourForm").submit(function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

$.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
       SaveFields(value); // my function that saves to db via Ajax call
     });
  });

$("#yourForm").submit(); // or using your own $.ajax submit call

});
```